# Update Horizontal Progress Bar width programmatically (In horizontal scrollview)

Tags: android, android-progressbar, horizontalscrollview

I have a progress bar in scroll view and I would like to modify the width programmatically, but it's looks like it's impossible, in the xml I have only Progress bar like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And the code is very simple too:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
progressBar.setMinimumWidth(3000);
progressBar.invalidate();   // tried called invalidate although setMinimumWidth called requestLayout, not help
```

I also tried to set layout width, like this:

```
progressBar.getLayoutParams().width = 3000;
progressBar.invalidate();
```

But found it's works only for progressbar that not in scroll view...

How can I update progress bar width (in horizontal scroll view)? and why the scroll view defect the progress bar width?

Comment: In the future, please do not delete a question, then re-ask it right away.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I did it because the big changes in the original question, but got your comment and will not do it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: "I did it because the big changes in the original question" -- that's what the "edit" link is for. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting the params the right way. Try this:

```
HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams params = (HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams) progressBar.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 3000;
progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```